# TimesTen - correct way to reinstall schema

Tags: oracle, timesten

I have TimesTen local store which open cache connect to an Oracle data store.
Sometimes I need to drop the whole Oracle schema (Entities changes etc..), so I simply drop every table, and recreate it.
The problem I'm facing at this stage is by getting inifite XLA messages 
(in the TimesTen side) for every entity in every table (I get update, add and delete events).

To solve the problem I have to truncate the inner Oracle tables.

I understand that dropping cached table without doing something with the cachegroup is problematic.

What is the right way to drop an entire schema?
Is truncating the TimesTen inner tables' a good solution?

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. The best way to change or drop an Oracle schema when TimesTen Cache groups use that schema:
   When an Oracle schema needs to be modified or dropped, you should always first stop and drop the associated TimesTen Cache groups.  Once the Oracle schema has been modified or cre-created, then you should re-create and start the associated TimesTen cache groups.
2. Dealing with unwanted XLA messages:
   XLA is an asynchronous way to see committed inserts/updates/deletes/merges and DDL on tables of interest.
   If you know that you want to drop a table, but do not want to see the XLA messages associated with that table while it is being re-created, then you can just stop the C, C++ or Java program that is listening for those XLA messages.  If you have to keep your XLA listening program running while the table is dropped, you can use the XLA API to stop listening to that table until it has been re-created.